# IntelliJ cannot resolve Cloudbees maven plugin dependency

Tags: java, maven, plugins, intellij-idea, cloudbees

I try to deploy Cloudbees applications using Maven from IntelliJ, but IntelliJ highlights the plugin declaration. The error is : `Plugin '''com.cloudbees:bees-maven-plugin:1.3.2''' not found.`

Maven goals are working. Here is the plugin declaration in my pom :

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>cloudbees-public-release</id>
        <url>http://repository-cloudbees.forge.cloudbees.com/public-release</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.cloudbees</groupId>
            <artifactId>bees-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you check if you find the file in the `m2.repository` on your local..?

Comment: I cannot. I am behind a proxy, my current settings are working for dependencies downloading, but maybe I need additional configuration for plugin repositories ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first did not work, but after `mvn clean install` in cmd started normally and Intellij Idea found it.
Try also run `mvn bees:run`.

Comment: Thanks, running mvn bees:run in command line did the trick. It seems like IntelliJ do not download plugin dependencies by itself, or forget to use project specific maven settings.xml file to do so (I was overriding it)

Comment: I had the same issues, but everything was in the same pom.xml. Good that it helped.